# How do you use link_to towards a value in a for each code block?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to make my course title a link but I cannot figure out the syntax how to make it so.

```
  <% @courses.each do |course| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= course.title %></td>
      <td><%= link_to 'Show', lessons_path(course) %></td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<% @courses.each do |course| %>
   <tr>
      <td><%= link_to course.title, lessons_path(course) %></td>
   </tr>
<% end %>
```

But question is how many columns do you have?

Comment: So it's ok. My pleasure Sir ;)